# pgfplots function stops in the middle of graph?

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to plot the function `$\sqrt{x^2 - 4x + 13}$` using pgfplots, with domain restricted to positive x>0. I have the domain set to max 10 for sake of keeping my graph zoomed into the area near the origin.

This is what I'm getting:
[image]

And this is my code:

```
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\pgfplotsset{
every axis legend/.append style={ at={(1.05,0.95)}, anchor=north west
}}
\begin{axis}[
 axis lines = left,
    xlabel = \(x\),
    ylabel = \(y\),
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=10,
]
\addplot[color=red]{(x^2-4*x+13)^(0.5)}[domain=0:10];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Your writing of the `domain=0:10` is on wrong place. It should be in `axis` preamble or in the square bracket of `addplot` macro:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18,
             every axis legend/.append style={at={(1.05,0.95)}, anchor=north west}
            }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
 axis lines = left,
    xlabel = \(x\),
    ylabel = \(y\),
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=10,
    domain=0:10   % <---
]
\addplot[color=red]{(x^2-4*x+13)^(0.5)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! fixed :)))